# First column value and upper row differences

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two questions

1) How is it possible to get the text of the first column of a matrix, depending on the position of the max value in a column? I tried all kinds of different formulas but can't seem to get this.

2) How can I with formulas determine the difference between the upper and the upper but one row? For the first column I need a difference of 5, for the second 2, for the third 9. I could do this with something like `=if(C1<>"";C1;B1)`, but there could be gaps of 50 cells in the first row of my matrix. If this isn't possible, I'll solve this with VBA.

[image: example]

Comment: You cannot concatenate an unknown number of matching values together unless you write a complicated formula that allows for the maximum number of matches. Either accept the first matching answer or use VBA to concatenate matches together properly. btw, it you had indeed tried *'all kinds of different formulas'* then the least you could have done would be to offer one (working or not) to show that you have at least tried to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: @Jeeped are you talking about the first or the second question now? If it is about the `B / D`, one of them is good enough. If it's about the head, guess I'll have to do that with VBA in that case. If you don't believe me that's not my problem. If formulas don't work I'll delete them, besides that it's all Dutch formulas. The formulas were all variations of ones with `Index`, `Match` and `Max`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> <sup>1) How is it possible to get the text of the first column of a matrix, depending on the position of the max value in a column? I tried all kinds of different formulas but can't seem to get this.</sup>

In C13 as a standard formula,

```
=INDEX($B4:$B10, MATCH(MAX(C4:C10), C4:C10, 0))
```

[image: difference_letter]

> <sup>2) How can I with formulas determine the difference between the upper and the upper but one row? For the first column I need a difference of 5, for the second 2, for the third 9. I could do this with something like =if(C1<>"";C1;B1), but there could be gaps of 50 cells in the first row of my matrix. If this isn't possible, I'll solve this with VBA.</sup>

In C14 as a standard formula,

```
=ABS(INDEX(2:2, MATCH(1E+99, $A2:C2))-INDEX(3:3, MATCH(1E+99, $A3:C3)))
```

[image: difference_last_number]

Comment: The first one works fine, I'm having trouble with the second one though. Is it possible that it doesn't work because there's a string in my cell `B3`? Error: `#N/B`